# How to display a text in XAML which contains double and single quotation marks?

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my XAML file I want to display this text which contains **double** **and** **single** quotation marks:

> You shouldn't choose "Copy if New".

None of these work:

```
<TextBlock Text="You shouldn't choose "Copy if New":"/>
<TextBlock Text="You shouldn't choose ""Copy if New"":"/>
<TextBlock Text="You shouldn't choose \"Copy if New\":"/>
<TextBlock Text='You shouldn't choose \"Copy if New\":'/>
<TextBlock Text='You shouldn\'t choose \"Copy if New\":'/>
```

I give up, can I do this in XAML?

Comment: Some books (like WPF 4 by Adam Nathan, Page 34) do describe that it can be escaped using backslash. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You should encode the special characters:

```
<TextBlock Text='You shouldn&apos;t choose &quot;Copy if New&quot;:'/>
```

- `&apos;` for `'`
- `&quot;` for `"`

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to encode special chars you could use:

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Text>
     You shouldn't choose "Copy if New":
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Solution is good but there are syntax errors : 1) you forgot the '/' for the "TextBlock.Text" end-tag 2) you're missing a 't' in the "TextBlock" end-tag

Comment: Yes, you're right! I misspelled the code. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 9):

There are defined XML escapes `&amp;` `&quot;` for " and `&amp;` `&apos;` for ' -- if the XML handling in `XAML` doesn't interpret those properly, then start to worry.