# Is it possible to add "" (Quotes) to a binding using StringFormat

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, string-formatting

So I have a `TextBlock` bound to a property on my object like so:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FriendlyName}" Margin="0,5,0,5"/>
```

I would now like to surround this text in quotes and add a hyphen to it so I tried:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FriendlyName, StringFormat= - \"{0}\"}" Margin="0,5,0,5"/>
```

But got a number of errors.

I also tried (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103337/how-to-display-a-text-in-xaml-which-contains-double-and-single-quotation-marks)):

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FriendlyName, StringFormat= -  &quot;{0} &quot;}" Margin="0,5,0,5"/>
```

but got the error:

> Error 4   Names and Values in a MarkupExtension cannot contain quotes.
>   The MarkupExtension arguments ' FriendlyName, StringFormat= -  "{0}
>   "}' are not valid

So I was wondering is it possible to add quotes to a binding using `StringFormat`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add single quotes:

```
 <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FriendlyName, StringFormat='-  &quot;{0}&quot;'}" Margin="0,5,0,5"/>
```

Or you can use `MultiBinding`:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5,0,5">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat=" -  &quot;{0}&quot;">
            <Binding Path="FriendlyName" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the binding element explicitly (no multi-binding necessary):

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5,0,5">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding StringFormat="{} -  &quot;{0}&quot;" Path="FriendlyName"/>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```